# Pthreads matrix multiplication error

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I want to use pthreads on my existing serial matrix multiplication code. My goal is to achieve better execution time using pthreads, simply to achieve speed-up. But at that point I'm stuck. My original serial code, works just fine, and I finish 1000x1000 square matrix multiplication in about 15 seconds. But when I execute my current pthreads program, I get a segmentation fault. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

int SIZE, NTHREADS;
int **A, **B, **C;

void init()
{
    int i, j;

    A = (int**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        A[i] = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    B = (int**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        B[i] = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    C = (int**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        C[i] = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            A[i][j] = rand()%100;
            B[i][j] = rand()%100;
        }
    }
}

void mm(int tid)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int start = tid * SIZE/NTHREADS;
    int end = (tid+1) * (SIZE/NTHREADS) - 1;

    for(i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int tid = *((int *) arg);
    mm(tid);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t* threads;
    int rc, i;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <size_of_square_matrix> <number_of_threads>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);
    NTHREADS = atoi(argv[2]);
    init();
    threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(NTHREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;


    begin = clock();

    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)i);
        assert(rc == 0);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        assert(rc == 0);
    } 

    end = clock();

    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Elapsed time: %.2lf seconds.\n", time_spent);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        free((void *)A[i]);
    free((void *)A);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        free((void *)B[i]);
    free((void *)B);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        free((void *)C[i]);
    free((void *)C);

    free(threads);

    return 0;
}
```

If someone could help me make my pthreads program run, and achieve some speed-up I would be glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, you should retrieve the index using

```
int tid = (int)arg;
```

(Your code is effectively treating the loop counter as an address then dereferencing addresses at or around 0.  These addresses may not be readable by your process and/or won't be suitably aligned, hence the seg fault)

The above change might get things working for you but note that passing an `int` as a `void*` isn't completely correct.  It relies on `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void*)` which is likely but not guaranteed to be true.  If you cared about this, you could either allocate memory for the data you pass to each thread instead or pass the address of `i` and include synchronisation to ensure that you wait after each `pthread_create` call until the thread has been scheduled and has read its arg.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem, now it is running, but the running time is larger than my serial code. Now for 1000x1000 square matrix I get about 23 seconds, which is 8 more than my serial code.

Comment: If you run more threads than you have available processor cores, you'll lose time to thread rescheduling.  More threads doesn't necessarily mean greater performance.

Comment: I have Intel i5 processor, and I run it with 10 threads, and get about 23 seconds, if I reduce threads to 5 again get similar, and if I reduce to 2, I get about 16,17 seconds. But still more time than my original serial code. Any help on that?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything obvious.  Rounding errors in integer arithmetic mean that `mm` isn't distributing work evenly between threads in all cases but that doesn't explain why 2 threads are slower than 1

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the solution. I will try to look for the speed up answer, somewhere else.